# Solve an equation involving logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$ (\log_{10}x)^2 = 3 \log_{10}x$

Should I do it in this way:

$\log_{10}x^2=3\log_{10}x$

$\frac{\log_{10}x^2}{\log_{10}x}=3$

Is it right?

If I continue like this, I get only one answer whereas my book gives two answers! Please help?

Comment: Why do you think that $(log_{10} x)^{2} = log_{10} x^2$

Comment: Is it wrong? :( Ooops....

Comment: We have $log_{10}x^2 = 2log_{10} |x|$ which is not necessarily equal to $(log_{10}x)^{2}$.

Comment: Oh...understood...thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the number $\log_{10} x$ is lets just call it $y$, so $y = \log_{10} x$.  Now
$$(\log_{10}x)^2 = 3\log_{10}x$$
becomes
$$y^2 = 3y.$$
This equation has two solutions, $y = 0$ and $y = 3$.  So your original equation will have two solutions, one is found by solving
$$\log_{10}x = 0$$
and the other is found by solving
$$\log_{10}x = 3.$$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $\log_{10}x=t$ we get $t^2=3t$

$t^2-3t=0$

$t(t-3)=9$

$t=0$

$t=3$

$\log_{10}x=3$

$x=10^{3}$

$\log_{10}x=0$

$x=1$